# What is the way to move a material above another?

Tags: materials

When I create a new material it is listed last and I don't know how to move it.

I'm trying to render a material together with a "Wire" material and I think that the way that works is when the "Wire" material is on top of other materials and then assign the other materials. In that way on the render the other materials will be on the object together with the "Wire" material Here is an example from blendswap -

- http://www.pasteall.org/blend/31068
- http://www.blendswap.com/blends/view/67420 (read the description)

  What is the way to move a material above another?

Comment: I don't think you can. Why do you want to? AFAIK the order of the list doesn't have any effect on the render.

Comment: I'll make an update

Comment: I thought of that too, but when you have the "Wire" material first, then when the other material is assigned, in the render the "Wire" material will be shown together with it. Pretty cool.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Delete the top material slot, then add a new slot and select the material from the deleted slot.

[image]

In your case, you'll then want to assign the surface material (bottom slot) with everything selected in edit mode.

Comment: Thanks. So basically, the material is not deleted when pressing it on the "-" sign? I'll try it in a sec.

Comment: @Vladimir Yes. Pressing the - button only deletes the material *slot*. The material will stay around until the blend file is closed, and even then will only be deleted if no objects are using it. Materials with no users (no objects using them) have a little `0` before them in the selector drop down.

Comment: Thanks. I'm more comfortable with the node editor so my knowledge on the standard materials is a little limited.